# One field floats incorrect in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-float, stylesheet

I've got a strange issue with floating the field in Firefox. Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox has other opinion :) Other fields are fine, but this one doesn't want to float correctly.

The question is in blue field.

Here you can see how it floats correctly in  [Chrome](http://oopsbox.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/tmp/p3chrome.jpg)

Here you can see  [Firefox version](http://oopsbox.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/tmp/p3firefox.jpg)

Looks like for some reason this blue field starts floating from the second column, not from the beginning of the row.

Here's the css that i use for fields positioning. Basically i make fields some % widht and float them next to each other.

Here i specify first row field

```
.deliver-week {width:35%;float:left;} 
.deliver-date-start {width:40%;float:left;} 
.get_delivery {width:23%;float:left;}
```

This one is for these blue and red fields

```
.deliver-or {clear:both!important;width:30%;float:left;text-align:right;}
.deliver-date-or {width:70%;float:left;text-align:center;}
```

This is for the 3rd row

```
.deliver-start {clear:both!important;width:35%;float:left;}
.deliver-day {width:40%;float:left;}
.deliver-date-day {width:23%;float:left;}
```

Could you help me to solve this one?

Comment: The form is located here http://oopsbox.wpengine.com/zakaz/ and the issue is on the 3rd page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because Firefox renders the select box as a taller element than Chrome, and the container of the blue text is getting caught on the `select`'s container element (because it's now sticking out lower than the others)

You can fix this by setting a fixed height on the container `LI`s - `height:80px;` worked well on my tests (provided they aren't supposed to be flexible heights for whatever reason)

Comment: Works perfectly! I thought that field height may cause this, but completely forgot about the container. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @alex no worries! Glad to have helped

Comment: @Abdul Malik Thanks for editing my question! Next time i'll try to do similar formatting from the very beginning.